# Generating a random vector of strings in C++

Tags: c++

I've got a problem with my function that's supposed to generate a vector of random strings. However, all I get is the first element in the vector is random and the rest is empty. Here's the code:

```
void losuj(vector <string> &vec, int ile){
    int i, j;
    string str;
    stringstream ss;
    char c;
    for(i=0; i<ile; i++){
        for(j=0; j<5; j++){
            c= rand()%25 + 97;
            ss << c;
        }
        ss >> str;
        vec.push_back(str);
        ss.str().clear();
        str.clear();
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Comment: doesn't `ss.str()` just return a string, instead of anything else? calling `clear` on that wouldn't do too much, I think?

Comment: Lose the string stream. it isn't needed. a local `str` inside outer for-loop using `str.append(c)` would be sufficient. And `<random>` would make this *much* cleaner, btw.

Comment: Please use character literals, such as 'A', instead of numbers like 97.

Comment: My understanding is that there are 26 letters in the English alphabet, but you are generating up to 25 different possibilities.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Should be `c= rand()%26 + 97;` my bad.

Comment: [Solution with `<random>`](http://ideone.com/N7uZfh).

Comment: Using `rand` in a modern C++ program is a plain horrible thing to do (and if we're pedantic also just plain wrong), considering the better alternatives. Same goes for using magic numbers like `97` which already resulted in a bug. Using `random` instead even avoids the whole arithmetic in the first case.

Comment: Btw, don't use that `<random>` solution with non-ascii platforms. (unlikely you would, but had to mention it). There are ways get around the non-continuity of character series on things like EBCDIC, but it really wasn't worth the trouble when I posted that sample. Sorry if that offended anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as WhozCraig stated, you don't need to use a `stringstream` here. `std::string` provides everything you need.

The reason that your code didn't work is that your [`eof` bit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/) was set through the `operator>>`. Calling `stringstream::clear()` resets the bit and makes the stream usable again.

Here is your code with slight modifications, working alright. I also added the fixes suggested by Thomas Matthews:

```
void losuj(vector <string> &vec, int ile)
{
    int i, j;
    string str;
    char c;
    for(i=0; i<ile; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            c = rand() % 26 + 'A';
            str += c;
        }
        vec.push_back(str);
        str.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot. Any idea why my version didn't work?

Comment: I added some info and a link to the answer for clarification.

Comment: don't forget about srand(time(NULL)) to seed your generator

Comment: Thanks again. I found that `ss.str().clear();` would clear the stringstream in a different question on stackoverflow.
@user3613500 I've got that in main, no worries.

Comment: @eilchner fyi, it would have worked had the stream been *inside* the first for-loop. And the `string str` in your case would be needless if you really wanted to use streams. Just an `ostringstream ss` inside the first loop, then pushing `ss.str()` after the inner loop completes would also have accomplished what you sought.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the state of the stringstream because you've reached `eof`:

```
ss.clear();
```